# Speed of reading a GeoTIFF using geotiff.js

Tags: javascript, geotiff-tiff, elevation, api, altitude

I am have created my own API to return elevations from GeoTIFF files using geotiff.js (https://geotiffjs.github.io/), but it is slow compared to public APIs.  For example, table below shows the tests I ran on my API showing that for 250 data points I can return elevations in 1250ms (ish), while a call to elevation-api.io (limited to 250 data points) with the same data is returning in just 200ms.

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────────────┐
│ (index) │ nPoints │ nPixels │ nImages │      time      │ elevation-api.io
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────────────┤
│    0    │   250   │   70    │    1    │ '00:00:01:281' │    204ms
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────────┘
```

When I scale this up, 2000 data points takes around 30s - too long for the intended application.

When I spew out approx elapse timings for all the functions for a single data point, I get:

```
00:00:00:005 start
00:00:00:010 getPixelPosition
00:00:00:016 getFileName
00:00:00:018 getImage
00:00:00:027 finished getImage
00:00:00:031 readPixels  <-- readPixels takes the bulk of the time
00:00:00:078 finished readPixels
00:00:00:078 finished
```

So the bulk of the time is spend reading the GeoTIFF - about 45ms.  Is this reasonable?  Here is the code for readPixels:

```
const GeoTIFF = require('geotiff');

function readPixels(img, px, py, id, boo) {

  return new Promise( (rs, rj) => {

    // check if we have the required data in the CACHE already; if not load it
    if (id in CACHE.pixels) { 
      promise = Promise.resolve( CACHE.pixels[id] )
    } else {
      const shift = boo ? 2 : 1;
      promise = img.readRasters({ window: [px, py, px + shift, py + shift] });  // this line is the problem
    }

    // when thats done, save result to CACHE and return result
    promise.then( (result) => {
      CACHE.pixels[id] = result;
      rs(result); 
    })

  })

}
```

My questions: Am I using geotiff.js in the best way?  Are there alternative algorthims that are faster?

Data being read is from: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/astgtmv003/

See also linked question here: [Improving speed of geotiff.js algorithm on large number of points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/358163/161669)

Comment: What sort of tiff you have? Check with gdalinfo the size of the image and if it is tiled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was also linked to an issue on geotiff.js, [for reference I'll link it here as well](https://github.com/geotiffjs/geotiff.js/issues/146).

The main takeaways from there are (I think):
 - Using the latest version of geotiff.js
 - Using a worker pool

I think the code you showed is fine, but may be insufficient depending on the use-case.

For example, if you know the sample locations up-front, it may be more efficient to cluster them, or read the whole window of those points and then use that raster to read each point.

To elaborate a bit more: geotiff.js works on a tile/strip basis. For each read it requests all missing tiles/strips and upon arrival decodes them (decompression + some other tasks). So, if you are requesting multiple tiles at once, and the source data is compressed, using a worker pool can significantly improve the performance.

Each decoded tile is cached internally, so using a cache per point (like your `CACHE`) may be a waste of memory.

I think it very much depends on the surrounding code, i.e how you actually call your function, if you can cache your image, and so on.

Comment: Can I just clarify the point about caching...so if I call readRasters() on thhe same point twice, the second time it will return a cached result from the previous call?  Yes, if I had known that it woul dhave saved me some coding time!!

Comment: Not exactly. It caches the decoded tiles/strips, not the return values of individual `readRasters` calls. Getting from the tile to a single pixel value is basically an array index lookup, so very cheap in terms of performance.

Comment: Does GeotiffJS support COG on Google Cloud Storage bucket? If so, can you please suggest the url format to use with GeotiffJS?

Comment: I have no experience with Google Cloud storages. My guess is, that it should expose an HTTP URL, but I don't know the URL format.